# How to obtain docker image digest from tag

Tags: docker, containers

I want to build a very simple system (thinking some lines of Python) that converts a given docker tag (e.g. `ubuntu:latest`) to the SHA256 digest of the image that tag is currently pointing to.

I'm aware that if we have Docker installed, we can simply `pull` and then list out the digest of the pulled image. I was thinking whether this can be achieved without actually pulling the image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Docker client does not (appear to) surface this functionality so you'll need to use a Registry client SDK. I am using Golang and have been unable to find an SDK that's easy-to-use and works across registries (I'm interested in using [Google Container Registry](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/) in addition to Docker Hub). You may be more successful with Python.

I've been working on a project with container image manifests and wrote a Medium post about how to enumerate manifests and manifest digests:

https://medium.com/google-cloud/adventures-w-docker-manifests-78f255d662ff

**NB** There are some inconsistencies with Docker Hub's implementation of the [Docker Registry HTTP v2 API](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/). For what it is worth, Google Container Registry (GCR) accurately implements the Registry API. I work for Google albeit not in the GCR team.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [crane](https://github.com/google/go-containerregistry/blob/master/cmd/crane/README.md) to get the image manifest, then use [skopeo](https://github.com/containers/skopeo) to compute the digest.

```
$ crane manifest ubuntu:18.04 | skopeo manifest-digest /dev/stdin
sha256:86510528ab9cd7b64209cbbe6946e094a6d10c6db21def64a93ebdd20011de1d
```

Alternatively you can get the same digest from the output of `skopeo inspect`

```
$ skopeo inspect docker://ubuntu:18.04 | jq -r .Digest
sha256:86510528ab9cd7b64209cbbe6946e094a6d10c6db21def64a93ebdd20011de1d
```

Or if you'd like to do it by hand without any of those tools mentioned above, try this:

```
$ curl -s -L \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json,application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.list.v2+json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer $(curl -s "https://auth.docker.io/token?service=registry.docker.io&scope=repository:library/ubuntu:pull" | jq -r .token)" \
  https://index.docker.io/v2/library/ubuntu/manifests/18.04 | sha256sum
86510528ab9cd7b64209cbbe6946e094a6d10c6db21def64a93ebdd20011de1d  -
```

In fact, a `HEAD` request is enough to obtain the manifest hash

```
$ curl -s -L -I \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json,application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.list.v2+json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer $(curl -s "https://auth.docker.io/token?service=registry.docker.io&scope=repository:library/ubuntu:pull" | jq -r .token)" \
  https://index.docker.io/v2/library/ubuntu/manifests/18.04 | grep ^Docker-Content-Digest | awk '{print $2}'
sha256:86510528ab9cd7b64209cbbe6946e094a6d10c6db21def64a93ebdd20011de1d
```

Answer (score 1):

The spec for this is defined by OCI in [distribution-spec](https://github.com/opencontainers/distribution-spec/blob/main/spec.md#pull). You can use a HEAD request for this since the digest is included in the headers by most registries. However, you do need to handle auth, and pass headers to accept various media types. e.g. for Docker Hub:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

ref="${1:-library/ubuntu:latest}"
sha="${ref#*@}"
if [ "$sha" = "$ref" ]; then
  sha=""
fi
wosha="${ref%%@*}"
repo="${wosha%:*}"
tag="${wosha##*:}"
if [ "$tag" = "$wosha" ]; then
  tag="latest"
fi
# echo "Looking up repo $repo, ${sha:-$tag}"
# Switch to the following for OCI media types
apio="application/vnd.oci.image.index.v1+json"
apiol="application/vnd.oci.image.manifest.v1+json"
apid="application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json"
apidl="application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.list.v2+json"
token=$(curl -s "https://auth.docker.io/token?service=registry.docker.io&scope=repository:${repo}:pull" \
        | jq -r '.token')
curl -H "Accept: ${apio}" -H "Accept: ${apiol}" -H "Accept: ${apid}" -H "Accept: ${apidl}" \
     -H "Authorization: Bearer $token" \
     -I -s "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/${repo}/manifests/${sha:-$tag}"
```

Which you can run like:

```
$ ./manifest-v2-head.sh library/ubuntu:latest                                    
HTTP/1.1 200 OK                                                                                          
content-length: 1416                                                                                     
content-type: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.list.v2+json                                                                                                                                            
docker-content-digest: sha256:34fea4f31bf187bc915536831fd0afc9d214755bf700b5cdb1336c82516d154e
docker-distribution-api-version: registry/2.0                                                            
etag: "sha256:34fea4f31bf187bc915536831fd0afc9d214755bf700b5cdb1336c82516d154e"                          
date: Fri, 12 Aug 2022 19:25:06 GMT                                                                      
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000
ratelimit-limit: 100;w=21600                                                                                                                                                                                       
ratelimit-remaining: 74;w=21600                                                                          
docker-ratelimit-source: 68.100.24.47
```

To make it easier to work with different registries, handle auth, etc., there are various tools, including [crane](https://github.com/google/go-containerregistry/blob/master/cmd/crane/) from Google, [skopeo](https://github.com/containers/skopeo) from RedHat, and [regclient](https://github.com/regclient/regclient) from myself.

```
$ crane digest ubuntu:latest
sha256:34fea4f31bf187bc915536831fd0afc9d214755bf700b5cdb1336c82516d154e

$ skopeo inspect docker://ubuntu:latest --format '{{.Digest}}'
sha256:34fea4f31bf187bc915536831fd0afc9d214755bf700b5cdb1336c82516d154e

$ regctl image digest ubuntu:latest
sha256:34fea4f31bf187bc915536831fd0afc9d214755bf700b5cdb1336c82516d154e
```

Note that Skopeo is not doing a head request for this, so I would minimize the use of it on Docker Hub to avoid hitting the rate limits.

Docker is also shipping a method to inspect remote manifests from the buildx plugin, which is also using a GET instead of a HEAD request:

```bash
$ docker buildx imagetools inspect ubuntu:latest --format '{{ json . }}' | jq -r .manifest.digest
sha256:34fea4f31bf187bc915536831fd0afc9d214755bf700b5cdb1336c82516d154e
```

Comment: is there a way to get all digests of a given tag? There should be some previous digests still in the registry